# Datepicker disable from ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to disable dates from ajax JSON, but the problem is it not be disabled and i

```
     var dateslist = response.d;
        var dates ;
        var s1 = [];
        $(dateslist).each(function () {

            dates = new Date ( this.property_reserved_time);
            s1.push(dates)
        });
        var yesterday = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 s1.push({ from: [0, 0, 0], to: yesterday },)


        $('.datepickerfrom').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 1, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: true, // Close upon selecting a date,
            disable: s1,
        });
```

Comment: you're probably falling in asyn situation. Post your ajax part too

Comment: which part do you mean? from the server or the Javascript?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/p/2140373/6206003.aspx?p=True&t=636613198828227982